# Mysql time-stamp type

Tags: mysql, database

This is my create event sql query

```
CREATE TABLE event (
     eid  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
     start_time  TIME NOT NULL,
     duration    TIME NOT NULL,
     description VARCHAR(50),
     pid         VARCHAR(50),
     FOREIGN KEY (pid) REFERENCES person(pid)
);
```

and want to write event query to do this
: Ann has organized an event with eid==1 starting at 1:00pm with duration 2hours on Oct7,2013 and on Oct 14,2013.

then i wrote query

```
insert into event(eid,start_time,duration,description,pid)
values
    (3,'2013-10-9 14:00:00','2013-10-14','Fun- party','AA')
```

But, output is very strange

```
eid  start_time duration description pid
3     14:00:00   00:20:13   fun-party   AA
```

it does not show the 2013 or oct and for duration some information is cut-off

```
how to write a right query for this problem??
```

Comment: You need to use the `DATETIME` datatype if you want the date stored as well as the time.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the table column as a "DATETIME" if you want date and time instead of just time information stored.  It's giving back just time information because that's all the table can store because you defined it that way.